# How do I add key commands to sprite?

Tags: python, pygame

How would i add key commands to the sprite plumbers? Below is my attempt so far but there is no outcome when pressing the up button. How would i set ud, and ld to change by 10 when button up button is pressed?

```
pink = (255, 64, 64)
w = 640
h = 480
ld = 0
ud = 0
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
running = 1
def key_event(self, event):

         if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
             ud - 10
             ld  + 10
def show_sprites():
    screen.blit(plumbers,(50+ld ,100+ud ))
def setup_background():
    screen.fill((pink))
    screen.blit(cloud_background,(0,0))
    brick_width, brick_height = brick_tile.get_width(), brick_tile.get_height()
    for x,y in itertools.product(range(0,640,brick_width),
                                 range(390,480,brick_height)):
        screen.blit(brick_tile, (x,y))

 while running:

    setup_background()
    event = pygame.event.poll()
    show_sprites()
    pygame.display.flip()

  if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        sys.exit()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             running = False
         elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
             w.key_event(event)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the lines

```
event = pygame.event.poll()
```

and the first occurence of

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
    sys.exit()
```

The problem is that both poll and get take events off the event queue so you are losing the key up events in the call to poll.

In other words what happens is:

1. You press the UP key
2. This inserts the KEYDOWN event into the queue
3. you call event = pygame.event.poll()
4. this returns the KEYDOWN event
5. you check to see if this is QUIT, it is not so you continue
6. you call pygame.event.get(), but the queue is now empty so the for loop does not get entered

Example code:

```
import pygame
pink = (255, 64, 64)
w = 640
h = 480
ud = 0
ld = 0
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
running = 1
def key_event(event):
    global ud
    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        ud -= 10
        print 'ud',ud           

def setup_background():
    screen.fill((pink))

while running:

    setup_background()
    pygame.display.flip()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
             key_event(event)
```

Comment: I tried that and got :
`AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'key_event'`   this is in refrence to:  `w.key_event(event)`  What would i replace event with?

Comment: I think that is because in your code w is an integer, but you are trying to use it as an object with key_event as a member function.  I have added the version of the code I used to the answer (which has some changes to the way key_event is called)

Comment: So that gives me this error 'TypeError: key_event() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)' how do I add a second argument / what would the second argument do.

Comment: I set it to 'def key_event(plumbers, event):' that displays 'ud 0
lr 0' but the sprite still does not move

Comment: I've edited the code again.  There were two problems, the first is that "ud - 10" is just an expression and does not change ud.  You probably meant "ud = ud-10", but that still does not work as it just changes the value of ud inside the function, you need to declare ud to be global to change its value outside the function.